# How to load a div in wordpress just when the scroll pass on the div?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to know if it is possible to have a div loaded only when the scroll bar passes over it inside a post in wordpress?

If someone knows tell me something to read or study about it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look into comparing these numbers... `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to `document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollTop`

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic